# Zend Framework configuration file format for headmeta

Tags: php, zend-framework, format, configuration-files

We can specify meta tags like below programmatically:

```
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

How the above can be accomplished through configuration file ? I tried

```
resources.view.headMeta.contentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that we can add following entries in the config file:

```
resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
resources.view.language = "en"
```

Then use the regular thing:

```
protected function _initView() {
    $options = $this->getOptions();
    if(isset($options['resources']['view']['contentType'])) {
            $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type',
                $options['resources']['view']['contentType']
            );
    }

    if(isset($options['resources']['view']['language'])) {
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('language',
                $options['resources']['view']['language']
        );
    }
     ...contd.
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.view) - It describes the configuration options for resource plugins introduced with Zend_Application.  Kidna buried in the docs.

The *contentType* value for example should nor require you to code anything in `_initView` method of your bootstrap.